Simultaneously Matrix Diagonalization
Given $ A_1, \dots, A_M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I am wondering whether there exist matrices $X, Y \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times n} $ (with $ r $ potentially larger than $ n $) such that $ X A_k Y^T $ is diagonal for all $ k = 1, \dots, M $. Here $X,Y$ do not have any zero rows.
To explore this, I expressed $ X $ and $ Y $ as $ X = [x_1, \dots, x_r]^T $ and $ Y = [y_1, \dots, y_r]^T $, where $ x_i, y_j \in \mathbb{R}^n $. The condition for diagonality is equivalent to requiring:
$$
x_i^T A_k y_j = 0, \quad \text{for } 1 \leq i \neq j \leq r \text{ and } 1 \leq k \leq M.
$$
This gives $ M r(r-1) $ quadratic equations, while $ X $ and $ Y $ collectively contribute $ 2nr $ variables.
My main question is: How can I determine whether a non-zero solution to this system of equations exists? Specifically:

Is it possible to prove or disprove the existence of solutions for arbitrary $ A_k $, or does the answer depend heavily on the structure of the matrices $ A_k $?

I would greatly appreciate any insights, references, or approaches that could help analyze this problem.

Based on what you've  written, just set $X= :\mathbf 0$ and select any $Y$

well, thank u. The question is fixed.

Surely it depends on the structure of the $A_k$'s (what if they are all equal?). You should request that $X,Y$ are full rank ($\{x_1,\ldots, x_r\}$ and $\{y_r\ldots, y_r\}$ are each linearly independent sets), or else the question is not interesting.
Also, it may be interesting to ask "for what $r$ is this possible?" For example, it is always possible when $r\leq n/(M+1)$. To prove this, simply take $y_1,\ldots, y_r$ to be $e_1,\ldots, e_r$ and then consider $W=\mathrm{span}\{A_ky_j\mid k\in [M],y\in[r]\}$. Since $\dim(W)\leq Mr$, we can choose $r$ vectors $x_1,\ldots, x_r\in W^\top$.
Without more information about the $A_k$'s, this may be best possible.
